How to Create a New Post on Ethereum Research?
I'm having difficulty locating the option to create a new post on the Ethereum Research forum. Could someone please guide me on where to find the "New Topic" or "Create Post" button? I've thoroughly searched the interface but haven't been successful in identifying the correct method to initiate a new discussion.
Any assistance or step-by-step instructions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

In order to create a post on Ethereum Research forum, you can follow these steps:

Select a category.


I've selected EVM. You can select any category with lesser number of topics so that it'll be easy to scroll to the bottom (i.e., to the section that says "There are no more EVM topics. Ready to start a new conversation?") in order to create a new post.


Then, scroll to the bottom and click on "start a new conversation".


Now, you can start creating your post.


You can even change the category from the dropdown.


After completion, when you click on "+ Create Topic", a new post or topic will be created in the forum under your selected category.



Thanks you So much Sir!

You’re welcome. Happy to help!

Kindly mark the answer as accepted so that it can potentially help others as well.
